# Regular expression for file extensions in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a simple regular expression to identify all filenames in a list which end with ".req.copied" extension. The code I am using is given below

```
public class Regextest {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 String test1=new String("abcd.req.copied");
  if(test1.matches("(req.copied)?")) {
     System.out.println("Matches");
    }
  else
     System.out.println("Does not Match");
    }

 }
```

The regex tests ok in online regex testers but does not function in the program. I have tried multiple combinations (like splitting req and copied into two regexes, or literal matching of the dot character) but nothing works (even the simplest regex of (reg)? returned a "Does not Match" output). Please let me know how to tackle this.

Comment: Why not just `string.endsWith(".req.copied");`?

Comment: Some of the files in the directory have a custom extension like ".err" after ".req.copied" (i.e. ".req.copied.err"). But ya endsWith does solve half of the problem. Thanks resueman.

Comment: You could use `contains()`

Comment: ".+req\.copied(\.err)?$" is the right regex. The string can begin anyhow, but must end with req.copied, except for the possibility to find .err at the very end.Do not forget to escape the . (dot), because it has the special meaning "any character."

Comment: @MohanVS  You do not need to write `thank you` to everyone ...using the little up-arrow next to the answers is the designated way to do so ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Main problem with `matches` here is that it requires from regex to match *entire* string. But in your case your regex describes only *part* of it.

If you really want to use `matches` here your code could look more like

```
test1.matches(".*\\.req\\.copied")
```

- `.` represents any character (except line separators like `\r`) so if you want it to represent only dot you need to escape it like `\.` (in string we need to write it as `"\\."` because `\` has also special meaning there - like creating special characters `\r` `\n` `\t` and so on - so it also requires escaping via additional `\`).
- `.*` will let regex accept any characters before `.req.copied`

##### But in your case you should simply use `endsWith` method

```
test1.endsWith(".req.copied")
```

Comment: Thanks Pshemo! I was using a single slash before the dot to denote literal character, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

As resueman said in the comments, you don't need a regex for that. You can simply check if each filename `endsWith(".req.copied")`.

```
if(test1.endsWith(".req.copied")){
    System.out.println("Matches");
}else{
    System.out.println("Does not match");
}
```

By the way, the above if-else can be replaced with `System.out.println(test1.endsWith(".req.copied") ? "Matches" : "Does not match");`.

Answer (score 2):

`test1.matches(".*\\.req\\.copied")` should do it but in your case you should consider using `endsWith()` instead of `matches`.

Comment: Make sure to escape `.` like `\\.`

Answer (score 1):

You should come up with a Regex that would match the whole string format, not a snippet:

```
String test1= "abcd.req.copied";

if(test1.matches("^.*req\\.copied$")) {
    System.out.println("Matches");
} else {
    System.out.println("Does not Match");
}
```

Also, your format was using `(req.copied)?`, which would match any case. Also, `.` symbol matches any character, so escape it for matching a dot.